Semi-differentiable function vs. restriction of a differentiable function
I am studying manifolds with boundary, and the definition of a continuous or smooth function on the domain $\mathbb{H}^n \subset \mathbb{R}^n = \{(x_1, \dots, x_n): x_n \geq 0\}$ is a function that is the restriction of a continuous or smooth function defined on a neighborhood of $\mathbb{H}^n$.
Is this definition equivalent to the definition that a function on $\mathbb{H}^n$ is continuous or smooth if we only look at limits of the function or limits of the function's difference quotient at sequences of points that stay in the function's domain? (This is the notion of left- and right- handed limits, or I think semi-differentiability.)
Does this equivalence hold for an arbitrary subset of Euclidean space that is not $\mathbb{H}^n$, possibly with some assumptions?

Note: My question seems to be a common one, but I can't find an answer for it. It is unanswered in the comments to the first answer here.
I have been searching up "extensions of continuous functions on an arbitrary subset of Euclidean space," and the results do not seem to be what I am asking. Call the definition in paragraph 1 Def 1, and the one in paragraph 2 Def 2. I believe this asks about taking Def 1 and extending to all of Euclidean space, this asks about enlarging the domain for an already open set, and several questions are about converting Def 1 locally into Def 1 globally by a partition of unity. I am asking about assuming Def 2 and "extending to a neighborhood of the set" to get Def 1.

Are you aware of the Whitney extension theorem?
